# Boolean Simplification of $ (a+b) \cdot (a \cdot c + a \cdot \overline{c}) + a \cdot b + b $

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Below is my simplification, but my truth tables don't line up, but I can't find my error.

$ (a+b) \cdot (a \cdot c + a \cdot \overline{c}) + a \cdot b + b $

$ (a+b) \cdot a \cdot (c + \overline{c}) + a \cdot b + b $

$ (a+b) \cdot a + a \cdot b + b $

$ (a+b) \cdot a \cdot b $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that $a\cdot b + b = b$.  So I think your fourth line should be $(a+b)\cdot a + b$.

Comment: By what rule? I went with 

$a+a = a$ and $b+b=b$

which is idempotence.

Comment: Got it, it's by absorption, and then $(a+b) \cdot a+b) is idempotence to $ a+b $. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great!  Can you tell me, what is "absorption"?  I know the rules but not the names.

Comment: I do not understand the proofs behind absorption, but the two forms listed in my book are:

$x+x \cdot y = x$

also:

$ x \cdot (x+y) = x $